# What is the return value after a successful INSERT using sqlsrv_query() in PHP, MSSQL SERVER 2005?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using the following simple code:

```
$aQuery = "INSERT into myTable (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 'Hello', 'Goodbye')";
$result = sqlsrv_query($myConn, $aQuery ); //where $myConn is valid and defined elsewhere
if (!$result) {
    echo 'FAIL';
}
else {
    echo 'It worked BABY!';
}
```

What is the value of `$result` if the query executes successfully, and how do I access the resource properly? `echo $result;` will print: `Resource id #8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the query fails `$result == false`

So in your code:

```
if (!$result) { //if result is NOT true
    echo 'FAIL'; //it failed
}
else { //otherwise
    echo 'It worked BABY!'; //it did NOT fail
}
```

Any value that is not `false` or `0` is considered `true`

---

Addendum based on comments below.

Only `SELECT` returns content.

Comment: I understand this. What I want is how to access the data in the variable $result, when it does NOT fail (as the value is false when it does fail).

Comment: @David Weitz - I have looked over the docs there and I do not see how to leverage the returned resource statement after a successful INSERT.

Comment: When it doesn't fail sqlsrv_query will just return a resource ID. It doesn't actually contain the result of the query. For an INSERT query you want to check sqlsrv_rows_affected(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc296178(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @neal - this seems to be the case. If you add it into your answer it would be the most correct answer. (In other words, the return value for an INSERT statement cannot really be used for anything other than verifying failure as in my example).

Comment: @LittleTreeX ... when have you **ever** seen an insert return anything??

Comment: @neal - Can't a man DREAM!? Seriously though, I was just hoping that maybe it would contain some other useful data. I am kinda self taught in SQL, so I didn't know one way or another if anything was returned from an insert. Obviously, I should have known this based on your tone :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the technical term for $result is a PHP "Statement Resource" (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx) which is a fancy name for "whatever the database returns".

So $result will contain whatever SQL Server returns for insert statements.  I think it is a number of the affected records in the query, but I'm not certain.  If you wanted to return something different, say the primary key of the record you just inserted, you would probably need to call a stored procedure rather than just send an insert statement.

Comment: yes,  but this resource is not normally a simple string,  and the methodology used to access it after a select statement does not seem to work.

Comment: I see your dilemma.  Does get_resource_type() give you any helpful info?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php

Answer (score 0):

Example from [Geeks With Blogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/05/08/how-to-let-php-get-data-from-microsoft-sql-server.aspx)

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo($row['ID'] . ', '.
     $row['Title'] . ', '.
     $row['Name']);
}
```

Where ID, Title and Name are columns in the table

Comment: I tried this, however after an INSERT this does not seem to do anything. In other words, the while loop never executes. This works perfectly, however for a SELECT statement.

Comment: My mistake sorry. I think jeremy's answer below is the closest you'll get, short of trying `var_dump()` on the `$result` variable instead of `echo` and seeing if there's anything of use in whatever object it returns

Comment: var_dump() seems to confirm what others are saying. The return value from an INSERT is useless. Thanks for this suggestion.